# Spring Nested Object How Can I Get With JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

in my spring boot project with mysql i have this model(ProduceCategoryModel), im using nested same object(ProduceCategoryModel) in a model for subCategories;

```
package com.eck.data.api.contract.model.produce;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

import com.eck.data.api.contract.model.site.SiteModel;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name = "produceCategory", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(name = "UniqueProduceCategoryModelName", columnNames = { "name" }) })
public class ProduceCategoryModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6532245350339799470L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "creationDate")
    private Date creationDate;

    @Column(name = "lastModification")
    private Date lastModification;

    @Column(name = "active", columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private boolean active;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "produceCategory")
    private List<ProduceCategoryDescriptionModel> descriptions;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "produceCategories")
    private List<ProduceModel> produces;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "subProduceCategories", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "produceCategoryId") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "subProduceCategoryId") }, uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "UniqueSubProduceCategoryId", columnNames = {
                "produceCategoryId", "subProduceCategoryId" }))
    private List<ProduceCategoryModel> subCategories;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "siteId", nullable = false)
    private SiteModel site;

    public int getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public Date getLastModification() {
    return lastModification;
    }

    public void setLastModification(Date lastModification) {
    this.lastModification = lastModification;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
    }

    public List<ProduceCategoryDescriptionModel> getDescriptions() {
    return descriptions;
    }

    public void setDescriptions(List<ProduceCategoryDescriptionModel> descriptions) {
    this.descriptions = descriptions;
    }

    public List<ProduceModel> getProduces() {
    return produces;
    }

    public void setProduces(List<ProduceModel> produces) {
    this.produces = produces;
    }

    public List<ProduceCategoryModel> getSubCategories() {
    return subCategories;
    }

    public void setSubCategories(List<ProduceCategoryModel> subCategories) {
    this.subCategories = subCategories;
    }

    public SiteModel getSite() {
    return site;
    }

    public void setSite(SiteModel site) {
    this.site = site;
    }

    public void addSubCategory(ProduceCategoryModel category) {
    this.subCategories.add(category);
    category.getSubCategories().add(this);
    }

    public void removeSubCategory(int categoryId) {
    ProduceCategoryModel category = this.subCategories.stream().filter(t -> t.getId() == categoryId).findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
    if (category != null) {
        this.subCategories.remove(category);
        category.getSubCategories().remove(this);
    }
    }

    public void addProduce(ProduceModel produce) {
    this.produces.add(produce);
    produce.getProduceCategories().add(this);
    }

    public void removeProduce(int produceId) {
    ProduceModel produce = this.produces.stream().filter(t -> t.getId() == produceId).findFirst().orElse(null);
    if (produce != null) {
        this.produces.remove(produce);
        produce.getProduceCategories().remove(this);
    }
    }
}
```

you can see table details here;

[image]

[image]

here is my JpaRepository service details

```
package com.eck.data.api.controller.produce.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.eck.data.api.contract.model.produce.ProduceCategoryModel;

@Repository
public interface IProduceCategoryService extends JpaRepository<ProduceCategoryModel, Long> {

    ProduceCategoryModel findById(int id);

    List<ProduceCategoryModel> findAllBySiteId(int siteId);

    List<ProduceCategoryModel> findAllBySubProduceCategoryId(int subProduceCategoryId);

}
```

i know No property 'subProduceCategoryId' found for type 'ProduceCategoryModel' ,
my question is how can i get subCategories data list with JpaRepository service without not create new model on project ?

happy coding!

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2023-07-11 14:51:43.221[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m2329[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'produceCategoryController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'produceCategoryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IProduceCategoryService' defined in com.eck.data.api.controller.produce.service.IProduceCategoryService defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.eck.data.api.controller.produce.service.IProduceCategoryService.findAllBySubProduceCategoryId(int); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.eck.data.api.controller.produce.service.IProduceCategoryService.findAllBySubProduceCategoryId(int)! No property 'subProduceCategoryId' found for type 'ProduceCategoryModel'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.eck.data.api.controller.produce.service.IProduceCategoryService.findAllBySubProduceCategoryId(int)! No property 'subProduceCategoryId' found for type 'ProduceCategoryModel'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.eck.data.api.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IProduceCategoryService' defined in com.eck.data.api.controller.produce.service.IProduceCategoryService defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.eck.data.api.controller.produce.service.IProduceCategoryService.findAllBySubProduceCategoryId(int); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.eck.data.api.controller.produce.service.IProduceCategoryService.findAllBySubProduceCategoryId(int)! No property 'subProduceCategoryId' found for type 'ProduceCategoryModel'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.eck.data.api.controller.produce.service.IProduceCategoryService.findAllBySubProduceCategoryId(int)! No property 'subProduceCategoryId' found for type 'ProduceCategoryModel'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

im expecting how can i solve with right way.

Comment: Don't post code as images, those are unreadable. Add code as code (just as your stack trace).

Comment: sorry, i just added code as code

Comment: Your property is named `subCategories` not `SubProduceCategory`. Rename the method accordingly. `findAllBySubCategoriesId` should do the trick. Assuming `id`  is the correct property. Unrelated but unnecessary are the `@Repository` and the `findById` method.

Comment: i will delete @Repository annotation and findById method, i also tried findAllBySubCategoriesId, it works ! thanks for your help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @M.Deinum i want ask you another question, when i insert new data it inserting double way, how to i get one way records ?  for example records by produceCategoryId not include subProduceCategoryId, i did not handle it..